# How to fix Kendo Grid MVC displaying footer total on first row?

Tags: kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I am not sure why this grid is showing footer totals on the first row of the grid.  Has anyone run into this issue and able to fix it?

This is for the grid total not group totals:

[image]

Looks like the `<tfoot>` element is generated before the `<tbody>` element.

[image]

Grid razor code.

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid(Model)
  .Name("SalesSummaryGrid")
  .Columns(c =>
  {
      c.Bound(p => p.GroupName).Title("Sales Type").Hidden();
      c.Bound(p => p.Title).Title("CATEGORY")
          .FooterTemplate(@<text>Total: </text>)
          .Width(200);
      c.Bound(p => p.Value).Title("GROSS")
          .Width(100)
          .FooterTemplate(@<text>@item.Sum</text>)
          .Format("{0:C2}");
      c.Bound(p => p.Comps).Title("COMP")
          .Width(100)
          .Format("{0:C2}");
      c.Bound(p => p.Discounts).Title("DISCOUNTS")
          .Width(100)
          .Format("{0:C2}");
      c.Bound(p => p.Voids).Title("VOIDS")
          .Width(100)
          .Format("{0:C2}");
      c.Bound(p => p.NetSales).Title("NET")
          .Width(100)
          .Format("{0:C2}");
      c.Bound(p => p.NetPercentage).Title("% OF NET")
          .Width(100)
          .Format("{0:P2}");
  })
  .Sortable()
  .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
      .Server()
      .Aggregates(aggregates =>
      {
          aggregates.Add(p => p.Value).Sum();
      })
      .Group(groups => groups.Add(p => p.GroupName))
  )
  )
```

I tried many different things, and stripped a lot of formatting from this grid. I believe this should work out of the box.

Comment: You try using ClientGroupFooterTemplate(), my friend?

Comment: Using `ClientGroupFooterTemplate()` I get nothing... https://pasteboard.co/HPY8tE8.png

Comment: You can visit this link to refer more, my friend: https://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/grid/aggregates.

Comment: @Tomato32 I use the demo page as a reference all the time. That's why I believe that it should be showing up at the bottom of the grid by default. I am working on a very large and old project. I have a gut feeling that some CSS/Jquery is messing things up somewhere... I'll keep looking. Thank you.

Comment: Yeah. I don't have the license Telerik, so I could not help you more :d.